# Идентификатор __block и Mac OS X  < 10.6

Tags: objective-c, blocks

Добрый день.
В своем "универсальном" коде (как для 10.5, так и для 10.6 + 10.7) я обычно использую такую конструкцию:

```
+ (id)some_method
{
#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
    __block id some_var;
    /* Операции с блоками */
#else
    id some_var;
    /* Аналогичный код, но без блоков */
#endif    
}
```

Т.е., по сути, дублирую объявления всех переменных. Мне этот способ не нравится, так как появляется куча повторяющегося кода.

Поэтому вопрос: что если инициализировать переменные всего один раз (не зависимо от того, поддерживает runtime блоки или нет) с идентификатором __block? Как на него будут реагировать системы, в которых блоки не поддерживаются (< 10.6,< iOS4.0)? По сути, они должны на него дико ругаться, но кто знает.

*P.S. Проверил бы сам, но под рукой ни одной машины с 10.5 нет.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему нельзя так:

```
+ (id)some_method
{
  #if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE __block #endif
  id some_var;
}
```

Или так:

```
#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
#else
  #define __block  
#endif
```

Comment: @timka_s ну точно, задефайнить же его можно! Спасибо, странно, что мне самому это в голову не пришло.  Преобразуйте в ответ, пожалуйста.